# How does c# figure out where "m" comes from in (m => m.SomeProperty)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, html-helper

For example, in an MVC app, I can use the Html helpers to create a label like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductName)
```

I haven't declared the variable "m" anywhere, but the IDE automatically figures out what I'm trying to do.  It's somewhat disconcerting that the IDE knows more about my code than I do.  I'd like to fix that.

I mostly want to know how it knows how to reference my model.

EDIT: Thanks for all of the answers.

So, "Html" is an instance of HtmlHelper.  "Html" is a member of the ViewPage base class.  Its value is set in the InitHelpers() method of the ViewPage base class.  The HtmlHelper constructor takes the ViewContext of the ViewPage as a paramter.  The ViewContext knows what model I'm using.  The LabelFor is an extension method on the HtmlHelper class.  And that's why the lambda expression knows how to reference my model.

Dots are connected.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to read up on lambdas, but what's going on is that you're passing in a function pointer to the `LabelFor` method.  Because `Html` is strongly typed (`HtmlHelper<TYourModelType>`) and `LabelFor` is declared like `Func<TYourModelType, TValue>`, the compiler (and IDE) can determine that `m` is an instance of your model type, and hence provide nice IDE drop downs for the members.

Sometimes people find it helpful to compare the other syntactical options at your disposal.  For example, this would be equally valid:

```
Html.LabelFor(SomePropertyMethod);

...

string SomePropertyMethod(TYourModelType model) 
{
    return model.SomeProperty;
}
```

Comment: So somehwere behind the scenes, ASP.NET MVC creates the Html object like "HtmlHelper Html = New HtmlHelper(ProductModel)", so when I call Html.[whatever], it uses the reference to my Model.  Then it uses the LabelFor helper method.  Right?  I guess I assumed that Html was a class with static methods such as LabelFor.

Comment: @Jim, that's pretty much correct.   To be precise, `HtmlHelper` on its own does not have a whole lot of methods.  But there are a *ton* of extension methods (`this HtmlHelper<TModel>`) defined for `HtmlHelper`.  In this case, `LabelFor` is actually defined in `System.Web.Mvc.LabelExtensions` -- a static class full of static methods that extend the `HtmlHelper` class.

Answer (score 1):

That is declared against your View at the top.

```
 <%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.EntryForm1>" %>
```

So your form inherits from ViewPage and it would understand what type T is.

Comment: Tell me about it! Thanks for +1. I have not been able to make any points today :)

Answer (score 1):

The generic parameter for LabelFor is the same type as your model:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>"
```

The parameter for LabelFor is of type:

```
Expression<Func<MyModel,TValue>>
```

So the compiler knows that you'll be passing in a MyModel object into the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently LabelFor takes a delegate whose signature has a single argument. The IDE sees this and based on that types m to have the same datatype as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The name `m` doesn't stand for anything. `@Html.LabelFor(n => n.ProductName)` means the same. It's an unary anonymous function that returns the ProductName of its argument.

Comment: So the how does the IDE know to link "n" or "m" with my page model?

Answer (score 0):

`m => m.ProductName` is a lambda representing an *anonymous method* which takes a single parameter, called `m`. So `m` **is** declared: right there in the lambda itself. The type should be inferrable by the compiler given the type of delegate `LabelFor` takes as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `m`; what you've posted is lambda syntax (in expression form). The portion before the `=>` is the parameter list for your lambda, and the portion after `=>` is the body.

In your case, you're using an expression lambda. It's shorthand for:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m =>
{
    return m.PropertyName;
});
```

In any case, the `m` parameter here represents a value passed to the function.